# Next departure in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

**Sorry for posting in the wrong forum..
Please refer to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/next-departure-in-java**

Hi i am trying to calculate the time to next departure based on current system time in Java.

I am so far not familiar with the many aspects of Java, but i have managed to get the program to work in most use cases with a switch statement and while loop, but it feels like i am using too many workarounds to get the code to work as intended.

The next step is that i am trying to complete, the task in a less tedious and more elegant way. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to how the task could be completed in a similar way but with other features of java? Such as arraylists, tables etc. that are suitable for what i am trying to accomplish.

Here is the code:

```
public class TrainDepartures{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int initialTime = (int) (time / (1000 * 60) % 60);
    int findNextDeparture = (int) (time / (1000 * 60) % 60);

    boolean foundDeparture = false;

    loop: while (foundDeparture != true) {
        findNextDeparture++;
        switch (findNextDeparture) {
            case 10:
                 System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 10)) + " min.");
                break loop;
            case 20:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 20)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 30:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 30)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 40:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 40)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 50:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 50)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 52:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 52)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 55:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 55)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 56:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 56)) + " min.");     
                break loop;
            case 57:
                System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - 57)) + " min.");     
                break loop;         
}
}
}   

}
```

Comment: Post at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: as said, try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Assuming your flyers are not capable of time-travel, using the absolute value seems wrong. The next departure is in 5 minutes. Or maybe it was 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your entire `switch` statement with

```
System.out.print("Departure in " + (Math.abs(initialTime - findNextDeparture)) + " min.");
```

You're treating every case in exactly the same way, so you don't need the complexity or verbosity of a `switch`.

(This assumes you also want to print that line if `findNextDeparture==53`, for instance, and any other value you haven't listed.)

Comment: Except that he does only want to display 10, 20, 30, 40...

Comment: @Sebas I've added something to mention that, but he's also covering 52, 55, 56, 57, which makes it rather seem as though he's added a case for everything he's so far encountered, but just hasn't had the energy to cover all bases... (also note "managed to get the program to work in most use cases", which suggests some might be missing...)

Comment: Right, you did mention that

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try. Change the switch statement with String format:

```
    final int departureTime = Math.abs(initialTime - findNextDeparture);
    String result = String.format("Departure in %d min", departureTime);
    System.out.print(result);
```

The output from Switch statement and the code above is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TrainDepartures
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int initialTime = (int) (time / (1000 * 60) % 60);
        //these are the minutes you care about.
        int[] departureTimes = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,52,55,56,57};
        int lastValidId = 0;
        int timeDiff = 0;

        for (int d = 0; d < departureTimes.length; d++)
        {
            if ( initialTime < departureTimes[d])
            {
                //keep track of the smallest value greater than the current time.
                lastValidId = d;
                timeDiff = (departureTimes[lastValidId] - initialTime);
                if (d == 0)//first time, were done.
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                timeDiff = (departureTimes[lastValidId] - initialTime);
                if ( timeDiff < 0 )
                {
                    //wrap around when you cross into the next hour...
                    timeDiff = (departureTimes[0]+60) - initialTime;            
                }
                break;
            }
        }       
        System.out.print("Departure in " + timeDiff + " min.");
    }   
}
```